# React Application Installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, cmd, npx

I want to create a React Application for my WordPress theme, and I get the below error.

Please what am I doing wrong

```
/*file location begins
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes
/*file location ends
```

```sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes>npx create-react-wptheme react-theme
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-wptheme failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-05T22_12_48_517Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: TIL people are mad enough to integrate React with WordPress. What's next, integration with NFT blockchains?

Comment: At risk of sounding condescending, but have you **read** the error message? It tells you right there it thinks there's a network issue and tells you more details are in a log-file that it gives you the full-path to, so have you looked at the `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-05T22_12_48_517Z-debug-0.log` file? If not, **why not**?